# setText not appearing / updating

Tags: java, android, settext

My program gives the user an instruction and then they have `n seconds` to respond. However when it asks you to `Do Nothing` the text view doesn't update at all, the other instructions pop up fine and they're all coded the same.

```
    public class SimpleActivity extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {

    String str = "";
    String strDirection = "";
    Random ranDirection = new Random();
    int intDirection;

    int scoreCounter;
    long timeStart;
    long timeEnd;

    TextView score;
    TextView allerts;
    TextView correct;

    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gesture);
        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

        scoreCounter = 0;
        catchValues();

    }

    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    public void catchValues() {

        /** Linked to gesture.xml */

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
        allerts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAllerts);
        correct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCorrect);

        initiateRandom();

    }

    public void initiateRandom() {

        /** Generate random move */

        /** Log start time of move */

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeStart = start;

        intDirection = ranDirection.nextInt(5);

        if (intDirection == 0) {
            allerts.setText("Please Swipe Up!");
            randomColour();
        } else if (intDirection == 1) {
            allerts.setText("Please Swipe Down!");
            randomColour();
        } else if (intDirection == 2) {
            allerts.setText("Please Swipe Left!");
            randomColour();
        } else if (intDirection == 3) {
            allerts.setText("Please Swipe Right!");
            randomColour();
        } else if (intDirection == 4) {
            allerts.setText("Do Nothing!");
            randomColour();

            doNothing();

        }

    }

    public void onSwipe(int direction) {

        /** Detect swipe and store result */

        switch (direction) {

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
            strDirection = "right";

            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
            strDirection = "left";

            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN:
            strDirection = "down";

            break;
        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP:
            strDirection = "up";


            break;
        }

        checkSwipe();

    }

    public void checkSwipe() {

        /** Compare time from instruction to action */

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeEnd = end;

        /** Verify the action was correct */

        if (timeEnd < timeStart + 2000) {

            if (intDirection == 0) {
                if (strDirection.contentEquals("up")) {
                    correctSwipe();
                } else {
                    wrongSwipe();
                }

            } else if (intDirection == 1) {
                if (strDirection.contentEquals("down")) {
                    correctSwipe();
                } else {
                    wrongSwipe();
                }
            } else if (intDirection == 2) {
                if (strDirection.contentEquals("left")) {
                    correctSwipe();
                } else {
                    wrongSwipe();
                }
            } else if (intDirection == 3) {
                if (strDirection.contentEquals("right")) {
                    correctSwipe();
                } else {
                    wrongSwipe();
                }

            }

        } else {

            /** Incorrect action, reset score and start over */

            scoreCounter = 0;
            score.setText("Score:" + scoreCounter);
            strDirection = "";
            correct.setText("Too Slow!");
            initiateRandom();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void correctSwipe() {
        scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 100;
        score.setText("Score:" + scoreCounter);
        correct.setText("Correct!");
        strDirection = "";
        initiateRandom();

    }

    public void wrongSwipe() {
        correct.setText("Wrong!");
        scoreCounter = 0;
        strDirection = "";
        score.setText("Score:" + scoreCounter);

    }

    public void randomColour() {

        Random txtColor = new Random();

        allerts.setTextColor(Color.rgb(txtColor.nextInt(255),
                txtColor.nextInt(255), txtColor.nextInt(255)));
    }

    public void doNothing() {

        /** Does nothing for n seconds */

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        timeEnd = end;

        while (timeEnd < timeStart + 2000) {

            timeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        if (strDirection.contentEquals("up")
                || strDirection.contentEquals("down")
                || strDirection.contentEquals("left")
                || strDirection.contentEquals("right")) {
            wrongSwipe();
        } else {
            correctSwipe();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `runOnUiThread(Runnable r)`  when you want to update your UI from a Non-UI Thread:

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
>   thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

Something like:

```
 Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // here you put updates to the UI

        }
    });
```

Alternatively use [`onProgressUpdate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)  method of `AsyncTask`.

**Reference:**

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html